# What exactly is a Typography component in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm working with the Material-UI component library, and see the `<Typography>` component used often. I've read the [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/typography/) and here is the definition:

> Use typography to present your design and content as clearly and
>   efficiently as possible

I'm not sure why this just doesn't resonate with me but it doesn't and seems vague. I went on to read more of the docs, and I see it used in conjunction with elements like the following:

```
<Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
  h4. Heading
</Typography>
```

Why not just use the following instead:

```
<h4>h4. Heading</h4>
```

I'm obviously missing the main use case and concept here and that's why I need some help in understand what exactly I use this for, so I'm not just copying and pasting components where I don't really understand their use. What is the use case for this component and why do I use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like most React component libraries with a common UI/UX design language, Material-UI abstracts away many of the textual elements into a common component - `Typography`. There are probably more reasons why this is done, but two of the larger ones that I'm aware of are:

- all text will automatically follow Material Design rules (see all sections starting with [Basic under the System section](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/))
- since all text inherits from a common theme system, changing your base theme will affect all `Typography` components uniformly allowing you to maintain a common design language whereas using an `h4` tag on its own will not

You can go to the [Material Design](https://material.io/design/) website for more specifics on their design language. There, you can also read up on their rules for [typography](https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#type-scale).

Comment: So this does make sense, but how does this differ from what `<CssBaseline />` does by adding that at the root of the app? Does it not already standardize all of this making the use of `<Typography>` redundant?

Comment: `CssBaseline` has a different purpose. Notice how [the docs](https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/#css-baseline) mention normalize.css. Normalize (and reset, sanitize, etc) are all stylesheets that set the baseline styles for certain things (all listed in the docs) to behave uniformly across browsers. For a more in-depth explanation that one I can provide in comments, I encourage you to research and read about the history of reset stylesheets. A good starting point would be to read about [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).